# numpy==1.20.3 in GCP

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

When invoking `tensorflow_cloud.run()` I end up with a following error:

```
INFO:tensorflow_cloud.core.containerize:ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.20.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5)
INFO:tensorflow_cloud.core.containerize:
INFO:tensorflow_cloud.core.containerize:ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.20.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
```

This specific version is provided in `requirements.txt`. Obviously, this the package is available on PyPI. Any ideas what's the cause for this error and how to solve this?

Comment: Not to familiar with GCP and tensorflow, but it looks like the highest version supported is 1.19.5 of numpy. So while you do have it in the requirements.txt, it's not on the list of supported/tested numpy versions.

Comment: @astrochun sounds reasonable, but I can use this version locally. What are the discrepancies that might be causing this. AFAIK GCP uses Python 3.8.